Java - Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Audio data is too big
I'm a new to java and programming in general. I'm trying to play a sound with the code below (in java Eclipse). But it says audio data is too big. Audio's extention is .wav and it is nearly 28 kb. This code can play 10 mb .wav sounds. (Audio file's name is phshc.wav). Why does it do that?
package tryouts;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.*;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
File f1 = new File("phshc.wav");
Scanner skanner = new Scanner(System.in);
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f1);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioStream);
clip.start();
String name=skanner.nextLine();
}

}


If your program is encountering an exception, edit your question and include the entire stack trace of that exception, including the full message, all at lines, and all Caused by: sections (if there are any).
